# Is there a way to avoid installing VS extensions like "SQLite for WinRT" for each teammember?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-extensions

We are developing a Windows Store C#/XAML application that has to (among other things) interact with SQLite database and display Bing maps for specific GPS coordinates.

"Official" way to do this seems to be to install two Visual Studio extensions - [SQLite for Windows Runtime](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e) and [Bing Maps SDK](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ebc98390-5320-4088-a2b5-8f276e4530f9). I have two problems with this approach:

- It is necessary to install them separately on machine of each and every team member. With new PCs, VS reinstallations and people coming and leaving the project, this can get tedious really quickly.
- Updates. Let's say I install a specific version of an extension and commit the project referencing that specific version. Then, a new team member comes in and I need to install the extension to his PC as well. However, in the meantime, Microsoft has released a newer version of the extension and I am unable to download the older one - and now, because of one new person, everyone has to update their extensions, too.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is to somehow put these extensions to SVN. That way, they are stored  in one place only and there is no hassle with constant installations and updates. I was able to extract .dll files from SQLite extension, but with the Bing Maps, there is a .winmd file as well as a native .dll. I am unable to reference .winmd directly, and loading it dynamically is, as [I've come to understand](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a78fdd8e-a108-4279-9e6b-6c87cd0a0f0f/assemblyload-of-winmd-file-possible?forum=winappswithcsharp), not possible.

Is there some way to achieve what I want and avoid all outlined problems? I hope I am overlooking something, because I can't believe Microsoft would decide on something so stupid...

Comment: They are not VS extensions.  Use Nuget instead, add them to your project, check it in.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please elaborate a bit? I've tried searching Nuget repo for both Bing SDK and SQLite for WinRT, but to no avail. I believe they are VS extensions simply because they are referenced via Tools => Extensions and Updates dialog. If there are any online resources dealing with this, could you please provide relevant links? My feeling that I indeed did overlook something only grows stronger...

Comment: @Hans SQLite and Bing Maps are installed as vs extensions. For SQLite you have many nuget packages, but they need you install the extension first, the one that installs the dlls in x86, x64 and ARM versions, needed for RT development. Same thing for Bing Maps with the addition of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

You will find the explanation and an example in this blog post by Oren Novotny: http://novotny.org/blog/how-to-use-extension-sdks-per-project

Kudos to the writer of this post, it saved me tons of work.
I had the same problem when trying to do CI with TFSBuild service in Visual Studio Online in a project that had Bing Maps. We can't install anything in the integration server because is cloud based, so I had to do a very long search to find the solution. It involves modifying the .sln file and putting the files in source control maintaining a precise folder structure, but when you do all this correctly it works like a charm.