# How to store list of required extensions under source control?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I need to build a list of required VS extensions for development and distribute it via source control so that each and every developer has them all.

Is there any mechanism to achieve that?

For example, I'd like each developer to have SonarLint, Fine Code Coverage etc. w/o asking to download all of them explicitly (e.g. via onboarding instructions)

I was able to find a very similar post ([Is there a way to avoid installing VS extensions like "SQLite for WinRT" for each teammember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502975/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-installing-vs-extensions-like-sqlite-for-winrt-for-eac)) but the link is broken there :(

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://claires.site/2012/03/24/how-to-use-extension-sdks-per-project/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm searching for. I need to have it on VS instance basis, meaning instead of asking 100+ developers to install SonarLint extension, I'd like to simply put it under source control and when a new developer pulls the code the extension is being installed for him automatically.

Comment: After my research, we cannot automatically install extensions through source control or other tools.

Comment: That's what I expected ((. Anyway, thanks for the investigation

Answer (score 0):

[Suggested Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SuggestedExtensions) looks close to what you are asking for, particularly the **Solution specific extensions** part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed, it looked like a thing that may simplify that process, but unf the extension is available for VS 2015 only ((